# Capture photo using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera

I am new in Phonegap. I want to capture photo using Phonegap. I tried the following code from docs but camera is not starting. Please tell me what I made wrong? My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pictureSource; // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("OnDeviceReady...");
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

    smallImage.style.display = 'block';

    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

    largeImage.style.display = 'block';

    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : destinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}

function capturePhotoEdit() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 20,
        allowEdit : true,
        destinationType : destinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}

function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : source
    });
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
window.onload = onDeviceReady;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
<br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button>
<br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From
Photo Library</button> 
<br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From
Photo Album</button>
<br>
<img style="display: none; width: 60px; height: 60px;" id="smallImage"
src="" />
<img style="display: none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me where I made mistake.

this is my camera plugin

```
<plugins>
    <plugin
        name="Storage"
        value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
    <plugin
        name="Camera"
        value="com.foregroundcameraplugin.ForegroundCameraLauncher" />
</plugins>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you check the error console? Both the console.log file used by the CLI or remote debugging w/ Safari or Chrome will tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: Also, did you remember to add the camera plugin?

Comment: I am not getting anything in console. Please check edited code for Camera plugin.

Comment: Woah - so for future reference - when you say you are using the Camera and you are *not* using the default Camera plugin, you really should make that clear. What is the URL for that plugin so we can check the docs?

Comment: Hello @RaymondCamden.. As I am beginner in phonegap so I am not getting the problem. Can you please give me working code for camera.? So that I resolve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Follow what Emre said below.

Comment: Ok Thank you RaymondCamden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Phonegap's own camera plugin instead of a custom one.

You can see the documentation here: [Phonegap Camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html)

Plus, while refering to phonegap.js, you don't have to put js/phonegap.js. You can refer it like 
src="phonegap.js"

If you are using Phonegap Build, this is the right way to insert your plugin :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>
```

Comment: hi, Thank you for Answer. I am using Eclipse tool. Where should I add the plugin line.?

Comment: You need to setup your app and add your plugins via the Phonegap CLI(Command Line Interface).

You can read more about CLI here : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: Thanks. But now I am getting ERROR : "An error occurred while listing Android targets while adding platforms" using CLI. I have also followed    [limk](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html) but still I am getting same problem.

Comment: Did you do every step on the link I posted above? Since I am using Phonegap Build, I won't be able to help you about this, sorry.

Comment: Hii...there was problem in my system. It was requiring permission to perform any task on that particular directory. Problem is solved after changed directory.
Thank you very much for your response.